# (select) event under <tabset> is not working after upgrading to Angular 11

Tags: angular

I have upgraded my Angular version to 11. And now wherever we are using (select) event under  in , the respective method in component file is not being called. Below  are files:

*admin.component.html*

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row p-3">
    <div class="col-md-12"><h3>Admin</h3></div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <tabset class="secondary_tabs col-md-12">
      <tab heading="User Access Data Files" (select)="loadUserAccessData()">
        <app-userAccessData></app-userAccessData>
      </tab>
      <tab heading="Approval Data Files" (select)="loadApprovalData()">
        <app-approvalData></app-approvalData>
      </tab>
      <tab heading="Archival / Purge Reports" (select)="loadArchivalData()">
        <app-archivalReports></app-archivalReports>
      </tab>
      <tab heading="Operational Metrics" (select)="loadOperationalMetricsData()">
        <app-operationalMetrics></app-operationalMetrics>
      </tab>
      <!-- <tab heading="Pending Approval Data" (select)="loadPendingApprovalsData()">
        <app-pendingApprovalData></app-pendingApprovalData>
      </tab> -->
    </tabset>
  </div>
</div>
```

*admin.component.ts*

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {DataService} from '../../shared/services/data.service';
import {UserAccessDataTabComponent} from "./user-access-data-tab/user-access-data-tab.component";
import {ApprovalDataTabComponent} from "./approval-data-tab/approval-data-tab.component";
import {ArchivalReportsTabComponent} from "./archival-reports-tab/archival-reports-tab.component";
import {OperationalMetricsTabComponent} from "./operational-metrics-tab/operational-metrics-tab.component";
// import {PendingApprovalDataTabComponent} from "./pending-approval-data-tab/pending-approval-data-tab.component";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-admin',
    templateUrl: './admin.component.html',

})
export class AdminComponent  implements OnInit {
    @Input('config') config;

    @ViewChild(UserAccessDataTabComponent, { static: true }) userAccessDataObj: UserAccessDataTabComponent;
    @ViewChild(ApprovalDataTabComponent, { static: true }) approvalDataObj:ApprovalDataTabComponent;
    @ViewChild(ArchivalReportsTabComponent, { static: true }) archivalReportsDataObj:ArchivalReportsTabComponent;
    @ViewChild(OperationalMetricsTabComponent, { static: true }) operationMetricsObj: OperationalMetricsTabComponent;
    // @ViewChild(PendingApprovalDataTabComponent) pendingApprovalsObj: PendingApprovalDataTabComponent;

  constructor(private _dataService: DataService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

  loadUserAccessData() {
    this.userAccessDataObj.getUserAccessDataJSON();
  }

  loadApprovalData() {
    this.approvalDataObj.getApprovalDataJSON();
  }

  loadArchivalData() {
    this.archivalReportsDataObj.getArchivalReportsJSON();
  }

  loadOperationalMetricsData() {
    this.operationMetricsObj.getOperationalMetricsDataJSON();
  }

  // loadPendingApprovalsData() {
  //   this.pendingApprovalsObj.getPendingApprovalDataJSON();
  // }

}
```

*package.json*

```
  "name": "portal",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "portal",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "lint:fix": "ng lint portal --fix ",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test:watch": "ng test --watch",
    "test": "ng test --watch=false",
    "test-coverage": "ng test --watch=false --code-coverage",
    "test:headless": "ng test --watch=false --karma-config src/karma.phantomjs.conf.js",
    "build:prod": "ng build",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --proxy http://proxy.jpmchase.net:8443 --versions.chrome=2.35",
    "e2e": "ng e2e --webdriver-update false",
    "build:skip": "ng version",
    "build:ssap": "ng build",
    "build:local": "ng build",
    "build:test": "ng build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE.txt",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "11.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "11.2.14",
    "@ct-tuxedo/angular": "5.0.0",
    "@ct-tuxedo/tuxedo-bootstrap": "5.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.7.2",
    "@ng-idle/core": "8.0.0-beta.4",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "8.0.0-beta.4",
    "ag-grid": "^18.1.2",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^18.0.1",
    "angular-file-saver": "^1.1.3",
    "angular-split": "^1.0.0-beta.9",
    "angular-split-ng6": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.5.4",
    "deep-extend": "0.6.0",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "ng2-dragula": "^2.1.1",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "ng2-tree": "^2.0.0-alpha.10",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "5.2.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "10.0.1",
    "ngx-treeview": "6.0.2",
    "pdfjs-dist": "~2.5.207",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "yarn": "1.22.4",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.14",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "11.2.14",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "16.0.3",
    "@types/file-saver": "0.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.25.0",
    "ts-node": "5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "4.0.7"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "**/tar": "^4.4.8",
    "**/adm-zip": "^0.4.9",
    "**/glob-parent": "^3.1.0",
    "**/serialize-javascript": "^1.4.0",
    "**/ssri": "^6.0.1",
    "**/trim-newlines": "^1.0.0",
    "**/ansi-regex": "^4.1.0",
    "**/nth-check": "^2.0.1",
    "**/set-value": "^2.0.1",
    "**/unset-value": "^1.0.0",
    "**/json-schema": "0.4.0",
    "**/ejs": "^2.5.7",
    "**/node-forge": "^0.10.0",
    "**/minimist": "~0.0.1",
    "**/async": "^2.6.4",
    "**/scss-tokenizer": "^0.2.3"
  }
}
```

In the above html when clicking on tab Approval Data Files, loadApprovalData() method is not getting called.

Comment: do you get any kind of errors in your console?

Comment: And where do you get the `tabset` and `tab` components from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/old/5.6.0/#/tabs) version
The event is renamed to `(selectTab)` rather than `select` , This was introduced from version 4 onwards [4.3.0](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/old/4.3.0/#/tabs) 
[Releated PR](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/pull/5002)

```
<div>
    <tabset class="secondary_tabs col-md-12">
      <tab heading="User Access Data Files" (selectTab)="loadUserAccessData()">
        <app-userAccessData></app-userAccessData>
      </tab>
      <tab heading="Approval Data Files" (selectTab)="loadApprovalData()">
        <app-approvalData></app-approvalData>
      </tab>
      <tab heading="Archival / Purge Reports"(selectTab)="loadArchivalData()">
        <app-archivalReports></app-archivalReports>
      </tab>
      <tab heading="Operational Metrics" (selectTab)="loadOperationalMetricsData()">
        <app-operationalMetrics></app-operationalMetrics>
      </tab>
      <!-- <tab heading="Pending Approval Data" 
  (selectTab)="loadPendingApprovalsData()">
        <app-pendingApprovalData></app-pendingApprovalData>
      </tab> -->
    </tabset>
  </div>
```

Comment: The issue is resolved after making it selectTab. Thanks